# How can i grep for multiple patterns, and print them on the same line?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a bunch of files that all follow the same pattern of data.

Let's say that this is the pattern i want to extract from:

`First part of text...patternA......Second part of text.....patternB.....Third part of text....patternC.....End part of text`

Currently i am using this:

`grep -P -o ".{0,5}patternA|.{0,5}patternB.{0,5}|patternC.{0,5}" filename.txt`

With this the output i am getting is :

```
1111 patternA
2222 patternB 2222
patternC 3333
```

The output i actually want is :

`1111 patternA 2222 patternB 2222 patternC 3333`

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the newlines at the end of each pattern.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: The man page is pretty clear: `-o, --only-matching:` _Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a  separate  output line._

Comment: `grep -o 'pattern' 'file' | column`

Answer (score 4):

if you know all 3 fields always exist, you could try the following with "paste"

`grep -P -o ".{0,5}patternA|.{0,5}patternB.{0,5}|patternC.{0,5}" filename.txt | paste - - -`

Comment: This was useful for me when I wanted to print only the integers from each line of a file, where each line had exactly 5 integers and other unneeded text.
`grep -o -E -- '-?[0-9]+' file | paste - - - - -`

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` to copy the parts of the line that match the pattern to the output, using capture groups.

```
sed -r -n 's/.*(.{0,5}patternA).*(.{0,5}patternB.{0,5}).*(patternC.{0,5}).*/\1 \2 \3/p' filename.txt
```

This assumes that the patterns are always in this order on the lines.

Answer (score 2):

With `column`:

```
COLUMN(1)                 BSD General Commands Manual                COLUMN(1)

NAME
     column -- columnate lists

SYNOPSIS
     column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The column utility formats its input into multiple columns.  Rows are
     filled before columns.  Input is taken from file operands, or, by
     default, from the standard input.  Empty lines are ignored.
```

For example (with a free useless use of `cat` to demonstrate that you can pipe `grep`'s output into `column`):

```
$ cat example
Fuzzy
wuzzy
was
a
bear
$ cat example | column
Fuzzy   wuzzy   was a   bear
```

Comment: This will combine output onto the same line even if it wasn't in the same line in the input file.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for all of the newlines to be removed; what did you expect?

Comment: I didn't ask for anything. He asked that it not break up the lines.

Comment: The example "This is what I want" output example shows all of the output combined onto the same line.

Comment: He just showed the output for one line of input. Presumably the file has more than one line that matches the pattern.